# pandas.read_sql returning series object type instead of sql type

Tags: python, oracle, pandas

I have a simple oracle query to retrieve data by joining couple of tables.

Query :

```
select a.col1,b.col2 
from table_a a,table_b b 
where key = 'some_key' and a.id = b.id
```

Using this query in the `pandas.read_sql` method

```
pandas.read_sql(query,connection_object)
```

In the resultant data frame the type of col1 and col2 are series objects instead of Oracle or the equivalent type in python.

My question is in what scenario `pandas.read_sql()` returns series object instead of the actual type?

Comment: your question is not clear. What data type have `a.col1` and `b.col2` in Oracle?

Comment: col1 is a Number and col2 is varchar

Comment: so what corresponding `dtype` would you expect to have in Pandas ?

Comment: int64 and object

Comment: it works fine for me - check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't reproduce it:

Oracle:

```
create table tab1 (id number, col1 number);
create table tab2 (id number, col2 varchar2(10));

insert into tab1 values(1, 10);
insert into tab1 values(2, 11);
insert into tab1 values(3,12);

insert into tab2 values(1,'aaa');
insert into tab2 values(2,'bbb');
insert into tab2 values(3,'ccc');

commit;
```

Python:

```
import pandas as pd
import cx_Oracle
from sqlalchemy import types, create_engine


usr = 'ora_user'
pwd = 'ora_pwd'
tns = """
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = test-rac-scan.wirecard.sys)(PORT = 1521))
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVER = DEDICATED)
      (SERVICE_NAME = <MY_SERVICE_NAME>.wirecard)
    )
  )
"""

qry = """
select a.col1,b.col2
from tab1 a, tab2 b
where a.id = b.id
"""

engine = create_engine('oracle+cx_oracle://%s:%s@%s' % (usr, pwd, tns))    
df = pd.read_sql(qry, engine)
```

Result:

```
In [12]: df
Out[12]:
   col1 col2
0    10  aaa
1    11  bbb
2    12  ccc

In [13]: df.dtypes
Out[13]:
col1     int64     # <-------- NOTE !
col2    object
dtype: object
```

Module's versions:

```
In [14]: cx_Oracle.__version__
Out[14]: '5.3'

In [15]: pd.__version__
Out[15]: '0.19.2'

In [17]: sqlalchemy.__version__
Out[17]: '1.1.5'
```

**UPDATE:**

each DataFrame column is an object of Pandas.Series type - it has nothing to do with the column's dtype:

```
In [50]: type(df['col1'])
Out[50]: pandas.core.series.Series

In [51]: type(df['col2'])
Out[51]: pandas.core.series.Series

In [52]: type(df)
Out[52]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

If you want to check a `dtype` (analog to Oracle column data type) use `DataFrame.dtypes` attribute:

```
In [53]: df.dtypes
Out[53]:
col1    float64
col2     object
dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort

Comment: df.dtypes works as expected and returns the datatype that i have been expecting.However when i do a type(df[col1]) that returns a series

Comment: @abhi1489, of course it does. Each `DataFrame` column is an object of `Pandas.Series`. I've updated my post - i hope it's clearer now...

Comment: Got it.Thank you.